# How can I save JComboBox edits when window focus is lost?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, focuslistener

I have a Java Swing application where some data are presented in editable combo boxes. The combo boxes are displayed in a separate frame. The frame is opened ad hoc when a button is clicked. The frame has no window decoration and is closed/disposed when it loses its focus (i.e., the user clicks outside the window). When the frame is closed, the combo box contents are saved.

This works well, except for the last edited combo box. For the last combo box, the contents are still being edited when the window loses focus. The `#getSelectedItem()` method of the `JComboBox` returns null because the editing was not completed before the window lost focus. At least I assume that is what is happening.

**How can I finish the editing and select the edited text when the window loses focus before disposing the frame?**

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```java
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Example extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }
    
    public Example() {
        Container c = getContentPane();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JComboBox<String> box1 = new JComboBox<String>();
        box1.setEditable(true);
        panel.add(box1);

        JComboBox<String> box2 = new JComboBox<String>();
        box2.setEditable(true);
        panel.add(box2);

        c.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        this.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Field 1: " + box1.getSelectedItem() + ". Field 2: " + box2.getSelectedItem() + ".");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The example class will display a frame with two editable combo boxes. If you click outside of the frame, the application will exit after printing the contents of the two combo boxes. You will notice that the last edited combo box prints `null` if it was visited only once.

Comment: Add a  `FocusListener` to the combo box text field that is used as the editor. See the `getEditor()` method of the `JComboBox` for access to the editor component.

Comment: One kludge is to get the JComboBox's editor component and call the "notifyAction" Action on it within the window listener: `textField.getActionMap().get(JTextField.notifyAction).actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(textField, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, ""));`

Comment: Thanks, both! I have figured it out now thanks to the hint about the focus listener. I had tried a focus listener before, but I had added it to the combo box itself. But that doesn't seem to work. The trick seems to be to add the focus listener to `box.getEditor().getEditorComponent()` instead and to put `box.setSelectedItem(box.getEditor().getItem());` into the `#focusLost(FocusEvent arg0)` method of the listener. I had previously given up on the focus listener idea when it didn't work as I would have hoped, but got it to work this way after @camrick's pointer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `FocusListener` to the combo box text field that is used as the editor. An event should be generated when the text field loses focus.

See the `getEditor()` method of the `JComboBox` for access to the editor component.